# php artisan migrate:fresh --seed give memory exhausted error

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, database-migration

I am using wamp 3.2.6 with php 8.1 and mysql 8.0.27

I am tring to seed tables using

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed memory`

however it gives me following error

[image]

I have changed the memory size in wamp to 1G, here is the display from phpinfo

[image]

But I am still getting same error

Comment: you should change memory in file php.ini but in directory cli, not apache2 nor fpm

Comment: I have verified the php.in also memory_limt is 1G there too

Comment: restart the apache 2

Comment: restarted apache a 100 times, while trying  different options

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it directly from command line as argument:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan migrate:fresh --seed memory
```

Comment: thanks, But what if there is a memory leak

Comment: Then it will be in your seeder; the command itself tries to get you out of the situation you are in.